# Overriding the << operator using two methods

Tags: c++, operators, ostream, overriding

I have to write these two methods, to print out what is contained within:

ex is an array composed tokenType tk (sorry, trying to save space and avoid posting the whole structs)

Unfortunately, I am getting a compile error that says: error: no match for âoperator[]â in âex[i]â

How can I fix this so it will override <<, so that the second method uses the first?

```
ostream & operator<< ( ostream & os , const tokenType & tk)
{
    switch (tk.category)
    {
            case TKN_OPRAND:
            os << tk.operand;
            break;
            case TKN_OPRTOR:
            os << tk.symbol;
            break;              
    }
    return os;
}

ostream & operator<< ( ostream & os , const expression & ex)
{   
    tokenType tk;

    for (int i = 0; i < ex.numTokens; i++)
    {
        tk = ex[i];
        os << tk.operand << " ";  //problem line is this one
    }   
    return os;  
}

struct expression
{
    int numTokens ;
    tokenType tokens[MAX_TOKENS_IN_EXPRESSION] ;
    void print() const ;
    int  toPostfix( expression & pfx ) const ;
    int  evalPostfix( int & val ) ;
    expression() { numTokens = 0 ; } ;  // default constructor
} ;
```

Comment: You can overload the `<<` operator.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I think your compiler numbers lines from zero, so you are off by one: the error is on the line one above from your "problem is here" comment. Does `expression` define the `[]` operator? Could you show the implementation?

Comment: Sure thing, I'll edit it in above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close - you forgot to reference the `tokens` array, and tried indexing the expression itself. Naturally, the compiler complained, because you do not have a `[]` overloaded.

This should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ex.numTokens; i++)
{
    tk = ex.tokens[i]; // <<==== Here is the fix
    os << tk.operand << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer after additional details**

You need to actually store from the ex.tokens then as there is a type mismatch. You need to do the following

`tk = ex.tokens[i];`

**Original Answer**

This not not seem to be an issue with `operator<<`. Rather, it seems to be that your type `expression` does not define `operator[]`.

To learn how to overload `operator[]` take at look at [Overloading subscripting](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr328.htm)

Comment: I see...I am not allowed to edit the file that contains struct expression for this project though